# Trouble connecting to database in standalone ActiveRecord app

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm writing a gem that's a command line tool, and trying to figure out how to get ActiveRecord to work within it to manage the database.

I started with a working ActiveRecord project (a Flatiron boot camp lesson), separately built a gem (`bundle gem gemname`), and copied and adapted all the file structure of the gem into the AR project by hand. Note that I am not using Rails or any other framework that might otherwise wrap ActiveRecord.

I've set it up the best I can, but I can't seem to figure out the last mile: I can't *do* anything with the database.

```
$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: []

$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.
```

Here's some pertinent stuff from the project:

```rb
# FILE STRUCTURE

LearnManager
| .travis.yml
| Gemfile.lock
| Rakefile
| LICENSE.md
| Gemfile
| CONTRIBUTING.md
| .rspec
| .gitignore
| .git
| app
| | models
| | | unit.rb
| | | topic.rb
| | | lesson.rb
| bin
| | setup
| | console
| config
| | db
| | | schema.rb
| | | learnmanager-development.db
| | migrate
| | | 20190210190844_create_lessons
| lib
| | LearnManager.rb
| | LearnManager
| | | version.rb
| | support
| | | db_registry.rb
| | | connection_adapter.rb
| spec
| | spec_helper.rb
| LearnManager.gemspec
```

```rb
# config/environment.rb
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

require 'rake'
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml/store'
require 'ostruct'
require 'date'

DBNAME = "learnmanager"

Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/models", "*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../lib/support", "*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

DBRegistry[ENV["ACTIVE_RECORD_ENV"]].connect!
DB = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

if ENV["ACTIVE_RECORD_ENV"] == "test"
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false
end
```

```rb
# db/migrate/20190210190844_create_lessons
class CreateLessons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :lessons do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.belongs_to :unit, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/lesson.rb
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

```rb
# db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do
  create_table :topics, force: true do |t|
    t.string :name
  end

  create_table :units, force: true do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.belongs_to :topic, index: true
  end

create_table :lessons, force: true do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.belongs_to :unit, index: true
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/support/connection_adapter.rb
class ConnectionAdapter
  attr_reader :adapter, :database

  def initialize(database, adapter="sqlite3")
    @adapter = adapter
    @database = database
  end

  def connect!
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter => self.adapter,
      :database => self.database
    )
  end
end
```

```rb
# lib/support/db_registry.rb
require_relative "./connection_adapter.rb"

DBRegistry ||= OpenStruct.new(test: ConnectionAdapter.new("db/#{DBNAME}-test.db"), 
  development: ConnectionAdapter.new("db/#{DBNAME}-development.db"), 
  production: ConnectionAdapter.new("db/#{DBNAME}-production.db")
  )
```

```rb
# Rakefile
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
require 'active_record'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require 'pry'

task :environment do
  ENV["ACTIVE_RECORD_ENV"] ||= "development"
  require_relative './config/environment'
end

include ActiveRecord::Tasks
DatabaseTasks.db_dir = 'db'
DatabaseTasks.migrations_paths = 'db/migrate'
seed_loader = Class.new do
  def load_seed
    load "#{ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.db_dir}/seeds.rb"
  end
end
DatabaseTasks.seed_loader = seed_loader.new
load 'active_record/railties/databases.rake'

task :console => :environment do
  Pry.start
end

# --------- FROM GEM BUILD --------- 
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require "rspec/core/rake_task"

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
```

```rb
# LearnManager.gemspec (excerpts)

lib = File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require "LearnManager/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.16"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"

  spec.add_development_dependency "pry"
  spec.add_development_dependency "pry-byebug"
  spec.add_development_dependency "pry-rescue"

  spec.add_dependency "activerecord"
  spec.add_dependency "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.6"
  spec.add_dependency "database_cleaner"
  spec.add_dependency "sinatra-activerecord"  
end
```

Anyone know how I can get this actually working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this also, but I don't use rake, I just use pure ruby.  Here are a couple of methods from my project where I use Active record outside of rails.

Basically I connect to the database,  check to see if the tables exist, and if not I load the schema file.  Once the schema is loaded,  I just use normal ActiveRecord methods to populate the database and do queries.  I have no need to do migrations so I have not tried that

```
class MyDb
  attr_reader :file_name
  def initialize(file_name)
    @file_name = file_name
  end

  def connect()
    @connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: "sqlite3",
      database: filename,
    )
    create_tables unless tables_exists?
  end

  def tables_exists?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.size > 0
  end

  def create_tables()
    puts "database is empty...\ncreating tables"
    path_to_current_file = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
    load("#{path_to_current_file}/ar_support/schema.rb")
  end
end
```

Then from inside a top level ruby script you can do something like.

```
my_db = MyDb.new("mydb.sqlite3")
my_db.connect
```

Here is an example schema.rb file that I also use.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180430230151) do

  create_table "chips", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "macros", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "chip_id"
    t.index ["chip_id"], name: "index_macros_on_chip_id"
  end

  create_table "measurements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.float "value"
    t.string "group_name"
    t.string "plot"
    t.boolean "test_result"
    t.string "test_expression"
    t.integer "run_id"
    t.index ["run_id"], name: "index_measurements_on_run_id"
  end

  create_table "runs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "source_dir"
    t.string "source_file"
    t.integer "macro_id"
    t.string "corner_name"
    t.string "sim_type"
    t.string "netlist_type"
    t.index ["macro_id"], name: "index_runs_on_macro_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "run_id"
    t.string "value"
    t.index ["run_id"], name: "index_tags_on_run_id"
  end

end
```

Start using the database.  (You also need to define your models)

```
chip = Chip.find_or_create_by(name: e.chip)
macro = chip.macros.find_or_create_by(name: e.macro)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great for a start. Where do you put the methods in your first excerpt? I've put them in my `config/environment.rb` file. But then where do you call `connect` from, and where do you use `@connection`?

Comment: Oh wow I think I got it working! However, my schema is just a tiny test schema so now I need to add all the actual columns I need. I guess I can delete the database at this point, edit the schema, and have `create_tables` create the correct db. But if I have later changes to make to the schema, how do I "activate" the changes without migrations? I tried `rake db:migrate` and got the same "No connection pool with 'primary' found."  error.

Comment: I tried to add a few more details, with a quick hack,  but don't over think it.  It's not a rails app, so the file locations are not so important.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have not had the need to do migrations for my app, but there do seem to be some gems that provide that functionality outside of rails.  For my use, the database is a way to make a large collection of text files into a searchable database, so if anything changes, I just re-create the database.

Comment: BTW,  you can also do everything in rails by just following the standard rails conventions and then use something like the connect method I have above to connect to the rails database,  that was how I started, but soon learned that it was more overhead than I needed to carry around.

Comment: Thanks. I agree exactly, I didn't want all the Rails overhead. I'll try the `standalone_migrations` gem, good call. Thanks so much for the help, this was the first solution of MANY that actually worked to hook me up to my database!